# can't get container to take apparmor profile in k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes

```
mount: tmpfs is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount tmpfs read-only
failed.
```

basedon documentation re: annotations, and the [containers creator](https://github.com/pducharme/UniFi-Video-Controller), here is the relevant part of my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: unifi-video
  annotations:
    container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/unifi-video: "unconfined"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: unifi-video
    spec:
      hostname: unifi-video
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: mira-b.home
      volumes:
      - name: dockerdata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: dockerdata-nas
      - name: cameradata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: cameras-nas
      containers:
      - name: unifi-video
        image: pducharme/unifi-video-controller:3.9.7
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - SYS_ADMIN
              - DAC_READ_SEARCH
```

IT specifically calls out

> If you get this tmpfs mount error, add --security-opt apparmor:unconfined \ to your list of run options. This error has been seen on Ubuntu, but may occur on other platforms as well.

but from what I can find (over an hour googling now), the way to achieve this is k8s is via the annotation line.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Could you past whole deployment? Because in this Deployment you describe the volumes but didn't attach it to container.

Comment: @NickRak yeah The deployment worked, I didn't post the full deployment yaml, only relevant top section.   Ended up posting a bug in K8s, got a reply.  The annotations are in the wrong spot.  they need to be moved down to the template spec (below replicas)

Answer (score 1):

Ended up getting the answer to this from k8s issue section.  Annotations were in the wrong spot.  Here's the correct way to do this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: unifi-video
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/unifi-video: unconfined
      labels:
        app: unifi-video
```

This results in successfully deploying the container with apparmor allowing tempfs mounts.